# Why is my system not starting correctly when booting Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, boot

> This menu allows you to select a hardware profile when Windows is started.
>
> If your system is not starting correctly, then you may switch to a previous system configuration, important: system configuration changes made since the last successful start up will be discarded.
>
> Profile 1

If I choose `Profile 1` (the only choice) Windows loads normally.

This menu always appears when I turn on the computer. Is there any way I can disable this menu?

Answer (score 2):

In the properties of your System, you need to [change the Hardware Profile options](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-configuring-multiple-hardware-profiles-for-a-versatile-laptop/5606571).

[image]

Perhaps specyifing 1 or 0 seconds in the bottom might work as well...

Comment: How to delete Profile 1, I can't click the delete button...

Comment: You will not want to delete your default profile.

Comment: Doesn't this appear if you disable any device in Device Manager and Windows is using a non-ACPI HAL (you can tell by looking at the Computer device in Device Manager).  Only way to rectify is to ensure ACPI is enabled in your BIOS and reinstall Windows.  Assuming windows XP (Windows Vista/7 requires ACPI).

Comment: but there's just profil 1 in the list..

Comment: See the bottom of my answer then.